# Aggregating data of a collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have document in mongoDB collection like this:

```
_id:'01',
country:[
     {_id:'01'
     city:[
       {_id:'11',
       name:'Chennai'}
     ]},
]
```

I need to save name of the cities of a country India into a collection city.

I tried doing this but its giving errors:

> db.city.aggregate([ 
>   {$match:{"Chennai":"India"}},{$project:{"Chennai":1}},{$out:"11"} ]);

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Where does your document says `Country` as India ? Please provide more docs + any input if you're passing to query & desired o/p before writing to new collection..

Comment: `{$match:{"Chennai":"India"}}` will select all documents that have a top-level field named "Chennai" that contains the value "India", that won't match the sample document.